# Ansible hangs on setup or playbook but SSH works fine

Tags: server, ansible

I am having an odd issue with Ansible and connecting to a host (any host)  and hoping someone can see something I'm not.  I can ssh directly to the host w/o any issue.  I can run -m ping w/o issue.  But that's where success ends.  If I run a -m setup it appears to connect and gather some info, but subsequent connections fail.

This is a server spun up on Proxmox (7.2.11).  I've done this 100's of times w/o issue.  That's why I can't seen to identify what has changed.  I typically spin up a container and set up w/ a ssh key (requiring passphrase) for root.  If a VM, I simply copy the public key to the root users authorized_keys.  Then run ansible playbook to add the user(s) and services along with locking down ssh.  So my playbooks initially run using the root user.  Ansible has always prompted for the passphrase and then go along it's merry way.

I'm using pipelining, but I've set to false in testing.

Appreciate any insight you may have... Thank you

Here's the output of a simple gather facts.  You can see that the first two `SSH: EXEC` return a result, but the third connection hangs.

```
➜  ansible git:(main) ✗ ansible all -vvv -i ./inventory.yml -m setup
ansible 2.10.8
  config file = /home/johndoe/NAS1-Mounts/Code/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/johndoe/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.10.6 (main, Nov 14 2022, 16:10:14) [GCC 11.3.0]
Using /home/johndoe/NAS1-Mounts/Code/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
host_list declined parsing /home/johndoe/NAS1-Mounts/Code/ansible/inventory.yml as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /home/johndoe/NAS1-Mounts/Code/ansible/inventory.yml as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /home/johndoe/NAS1-Mounts/Code/ansible/inventory.yml inventory source with ini plugin
Skipping callback 'default', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'minimal', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'oneline', as we already have a stdout callback.
META: ran handlers
<target_server> Attempting python interpreter discovery
<10.2.0.27> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<10.2.0.27> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="root"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/johndoe/.dotfiles/ansible/.ansible/cp/27e670244a 10.2.0.27 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo PLATFORM; uname; echo FOUND; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/bin/python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.9'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.8'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.7'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.6'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.5'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python2.7'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python2.6'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/libexec/platform-python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/bin/python3'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; echo ENDFOUND && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.2.0.27> (0, b'PLATFORM\nLinux\nFOUND\n/usr/bin/python3\nENDFOUND\n', b'')
<10.2.0.27> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<10.2.0.27> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="root"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/johndoe/.dotfiles/ansible/.ansible/cp/27e670244a 10.2.0.27 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python3 && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.2.0.27> (0, b'{"platform_dist_result": [], "osrelease_content": "PRETTY_NAME=\\"Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS\\"\\nNAME=\\"Ubuntu\\"\\nVERSION_ID=\\"22.04\\"\\nVERSION=\\"22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)\\"\\nVERSION_CODENAME=jammy\\nID=ubuntu\\nID_LIKE=debian\\nHOME_URL=\\"https://www.ubuntu.com/\\"\\nSUPPORT_URL=\\"https://help.ubuntu.com/\\"\\nBUG_REPORT_URL=\\"https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/\\"\\nPRIVACY_POLICY_URL=\\"https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy\\"\\nUBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy\\n"}\n', b'')
Using module file /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible/modules/setup.py
Pipelining is enabled.
<10.2.0.27> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<10.2.0.27> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="root"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/johndoe/.dotfiles/ansible/.ansible/cp/27e670244a 10.2.0.27 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python3 && sleep 0'"'"''
^C [ERROR]: User interrupted execution
➜  ansible git:(main) ✗
```

##### -m ping

```
➜  ansible git:(main) ✗ ansible all -vvv -i ./inventory.yml -m ping   
ansible 2.10.8
  config file = /home/johndoe/NAS1-Mounts/Code/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/johndoe/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.10.6 (main, Nov 14 2022, 16:10:14) [GCC 11.3.0]
Using /home/johndoe/NAS1-Mounts/Code/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
host_list declined parsing /home/johndoe/NAS1-Mounts/Code/ansible/inventory.yml as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /home/johndoe/NAS1-Mounts/Code/ansible/inventory.yml as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /home/johndoe/NAS1-Mounts/Code/ansible/inventory.yml inventory source with ini plugin
Skipping callback 'default', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'minimal', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'oneline', as we already have a stdout callback.
META: ran handlers
<target_server> Attempting python interpreter discovery
<10.2.0.27> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<10.2.0.27> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="root"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/johndoe/.dotfiles/ansible/.ansible/cp/27e670244a 10.2.0.27 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo PLATFORM; uname; echo FOUND; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/bin/python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.9'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.8'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.7'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.6'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.5'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python2.7'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python2.6'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/libexec/platform-python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/bin/python3'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; echo ENDFOUND && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.2.0.27> (0, b'PLATFORM\nLinux\nFOUND\n/usr/bin/python3\nENDFOUND\n', b'')
<10.2.0.27> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<10.2.0.27> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="root"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/johndoe/.dotfiles/ansible/.ansible/cp/27e670244a 10.2.0.27 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python3 && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.2.0.27> (0, b'{"platform_dist_result": [], "osrelease_content": "PRETTY_NAME=\\"Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS\\"\\nNAME=\\"Ubuntu\\"\\nVERSION_ID=\\"22.04\\"\\nVERSION=\\"22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)\\"\\nVERSION_CODENAME=jammy\\nID=ubuntu\\nID_LIKE=debian\\nHOME_URL=\\"https://www.ubuntu.com/\\"\\nSUPPORT_URL=\\"https://help.ubuntu.com/\\"\\nBUG_REPORT_URL=\\"https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/\\"\\nPRIVACY_POLICY_URL=\\"https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy\\"\\nUBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy\\n"}\n', b'')
Using module file /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible/modules/ping.py
Pipelining is enabled.
<10.2.0.27> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<10.2.0.27> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="root"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/johndoe/.dotfiles/ansible/.ansible/cp/27e670244a 10.2.0.27 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python3 && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.2.0.27> (0, b'\n{"ping": "pong", "invocation": {"module_args": {"data": "pong"}}}\n', b'')
target_server | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "data": "pong"
        }
    },
    "ping": "pong"
}
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers
```

##### ansible.cfg

```
➜  ansible git:(main) ✗ cat ansible.cfg 
[default]
inventory = /home/johndoe/NAS1-Mounts/Code/ansible/inventory.yml

# Use the Beautiful Output callback plugin.
stdout_callback = beautiful_output

# Use specific ssh key and user
# ed25519 w/ passphrase
private_key = /home/johndoe/.ssh/johndoe_default
host_key_checking = False
# For updates/maintenance as sudo user
remote_user = johndoe

# Set remote host working directory
remote_tmp = ~/.ansible/tmp

# Misc
allow_world_readable_tmpfiles = True
display_skipped_hosts = False
# display_args_to_stdout = True
# stdout_callback = full_skip
transport = ssh 

[ssh_connection]
pipelining = True
timeout = 30

[connection]
pipelining = True
```

##### my inventory.yml

```
➜  ansible git:(main) ✗ cat inventory.yml 
# Vagrant Host
#default

[workstation]

[server]
target_server ansible_user=root ansible_host=10.2.0.27 install_docker=true

[pve_container]
```

##### my .ssh/config file

```
➜  ansible git:(main) ✗ cat ~/.ssh/config
# Defaults
Host * 
    # Default ed25519 Keypair for all connections - unless otherwise specified
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/johndoe_default
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    # Always use multiplex'd sessions - unless otherwise specified in host def below
    Controlmaster auto
    ControlPersist yes
    Controlpath /tmp/ssh-%r@%h:%p
    ControlPersist 10m
```

##### ssh directly to host

```
➜  ansible git:(main) ✗ ssh root@10.2.0.27
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-56-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Wed Dec 14 05:06:20 PM UTC 2022

  System load:  0.0                Processes:              117
  Usage of /:   31.8% of 14.66GB   Users logged in:        1
  Memory usage: 11%                IPv4 address for ens18: 10.2.0.27
  Swap usage:   0%


50 updates can be applied immediately.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable


Last login: Wed Dec 14 17:05:53 2022 from 10.0.2.5
root@ubuntu-ansible-test:~#
```

Answer (score 0):

My apologies for wasting anyone's time.  My issue turned out to be a MTU issue with the Tunnel to the remote site.  Someone set it up with 1500 on the wireguard tunnel.  A packet capture pcap showed a bunch of `TCP Out or order`, `TCP Dup ACK` and `TCP Retransmission`.  Setting back to 1420 cured the issue.

Best